# What is the difference between bcpow and pow?

Tags: php, bcmath

Can someone explain to me if I should use bcpow() instead of pow() and why?

I understand that not all installations of php have bcmath enabled. So if I write an open source project, and want to have as few dependencies/requirements as possible, I would rather use pow() in my code.

But what are the downsides to using pow() over bcpow()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`bcpow()`**](https://www.php.net/bcpow) is a function of the [**BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library.

Quoting the introduction of it's manual :

> For arbitrary precision mathematics
> PHP offers the Binary Calculator which
> **supports numbers of any size and
> precision**, represented as strings.

On the other hand, [**`pow()`**][3] is limited to [floats][4], which have a limited size *(quoting)* :

> The size of a float is
> platform-dependent, although a maximum
> of ~1.8e308 with a precision of
> roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
> value (the 64 bit IEEE format)

Generally, you'll work with `pow()` and other float-based functions *(which are probably faster, and are always enabled)* ; but, if you need to handle very big number, you'll have to work with `bcpow()`.

Comment: But note that bcpow does _not_ support raising a number to a decimal power. Instead, it produces a warning and gives an incorrect answer: 

bcscale(14);
echo bcpow('10','1.3');

_bc math warning: non-zero scale in exponent_
_10_

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) the `bc*` functions are

> [...] arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as strings.

`pow()` is limited to the maximum supported numeric representation on the system it runs on.

Answer (score 0):

`bcpow` is used for arbitrary precision values. As a third parameter you can specify a number of digits after coma.